# Android-Django communication using HttpPost

Tags: android, mysql, json, django

I am trying to store data into the database table (MySQL) in the Django server. I tried using the "Postman - REST Client" google chrome plugin and the details were written in the table successfully. (Postman Link:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).
   But when i tried to communicate from android, i could not make success. Please help me out.

Code: MainActivity.java

```
`private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final String URL = "http://172.21.1.59:4444/polls/";
JSONObject jsonObjSend;
product.httpcommu.app.HttpClient obj = new product.httpcommu.app.HttpClient();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
    jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
    try {
        // Add key/value pairs
        jsonObjSend.put("username", "root");
        jsonObjSend.put("password", "root");

        // Add a nested JSONObject (e.g. for header information)
        JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
        header.put("deviceType","Android"); // Device type
        header.put("deviceVersion","2.0"); // Device OS version
        header.put("language", "es-es");    // Language of the Android client
        jsonObjSend.put("header", header);

        // Output the JSON object we're sending to Logcat:
        Log.i(TAG, jsonObjSend.toString(2));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, ""+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Send the HttpPostRequest and receive a JSONObject in return

            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = obj.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonObjSend);
            Log.i(TAG,jsonObjRecv.toString());
        }
    });`
```

Code: HttpClient.java

```
`private static final String TAG = "HttpClient";
public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // only set this parameter if you would like to use gzip compression

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();
            resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length()-1); // remove wrapping "[" and "]"

            // Transform the String into a JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
            Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;
        } 

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // More about HTTP exception handling in another tutorial.
        // For now we just print the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     * 
     * (c) public domain: http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}`
```

Code : activity_main.xml

```
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="product.httpcommu.app.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Json"
    android:id="@+id/btnsend"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Error Log:
02-06 00:36:46.800    1159-1159/product.httpcommu.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: product.httpcommu.app, PID: 1159
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at product.httpcommu.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: `when i tried to communicate from android, i could not make success` please explain what problem you are getting?

Comment: which line is giving the null pointer exception? can you put the full/partial stack trace?

Comment: Please check the error log now.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I think,

In your MainActivity.java file, you are sending the Http request in the click event of the button. Instead, create a thread and then try to communicate to your server. When you do it through the UI thread, it gets blocked and the application throws an exception. Just try with another thread. Declare a thread and in it's run() method, send the request. That should do the trick I guess.

Comment: Thank You Paritosh Walvekar. It worked when i tried with thread. But the application gets closed after hitting the server. Working on it.

Comment: It worked.Made the following changes:-
public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObjRecv = obj.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonObjSend);
                Log.i(TAG,jsonObjRecv.toString());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }